# How does delta modulation work practically?

Tags: quantization

How does delta modulation work in practice? And where is it used? I find it confusing that, in 1-bit quantization we use only 2 level; if we apply this quantization, there will be loss in information. So, why do we use this technique?

Answer (score 1):

One key point to note about [delta modulation schemes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_modulation#Principle) is that they quantize the change between the current value **and the previously quantized value.**

[image: Image taken from Wikipedia, image by Wdwd wikipedia user; license is: http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/2.5/]

The other key point to note is that, in general, delta modulation schemes are run at [sampling rates MUCH higher than the Nyquist rate would suggest.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta-sigma_modulation#Oversampling) Early portable CD players used a scheme called MASH (multi-stage noise shaping) on their DACs to allow cheaper, more accurate reproduction of sound.

I can't find a reference quickly, but I seem to recall that for the 44.1kHz CD sampling rate, MASH 1-bit DACs ran at sampling rates in the order of 5-6 MHz.

Comment: this looks an awful lot like $\Sigma \Delta$ modulation.  at one time i was very familiar with the difference between $\Sigma \Delta$ and $\Delta$.  now i need to look it up.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson : Feel free to correct / update.

Comment: okay, i looked it up.  $\Sigma \Delta$ has the integrator appearing **after** the summer, before the quantizer.  to be equivalent to $\Delta$ would imply a differentiator in the input.  actually $\Sigma \Delta$ has a more sophisticated LPF before the quantizer. and MASH is even more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

There won't be any loss of information if all the information desired to be transmitted is already quantized and band-limited well below the cut-off of the low-pass filter network that removes anything near the (delta) modulation rate (or its noise-shaped side-bands).  The high frequency 1-bit quantization gets "averaged out" by a low pass filter over a long enough period of time to transmit lots of bits (or signal levels) of information at a much lower rate.

Comment: well, there is **always** some loss of information in *any* quantization.

Comment: I was assuming the information was already pre-quantized, just not at the delta modulation rate.

Comment: for practical purposes if you have 24 bits or equivalent to 8 bit u-Law logarithmic compander, there is no perceivable noise or difference